# interstitial ad doesn't show when opening the activity again

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I created a simple app with activity that contains interstitial ad, and it works fine, but when I open the activity again while the app still running the interstitial ad doesn't show.

here is my code:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
    AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    });
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure ,your Activity is being recreated ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because when you "open it again", it's not actually creating it again.  It was likely just shifted to the background, and brought back to to the front.  Therefore, your onCreate isn't firing.

You would have to kill the process completely to get it to fire again.

Answer (score 0):

After an interstitial is shown you need to call `loadAd(adRequest)` again in order to retrieve a new interstitial to show.